# Ограничение процентов с распределением остатка на PHP

Tags: php, массивы, проценты

Есть список чисел, который является процентным соотношением. Сумма чисел равна 100.

```
$percent = [20.88, 14.93, 14.14, 13.29, 5.06, 4.43, 4.24, 4.22, 2.57, 2.51, 2.38, 2.18, 1.94, 1.80, 1.34, 1.21, 0.81, 0.63, 0.50, 0.48, 0.30, 0.16];
```

Необходимо ограничить максимальное число до определённого значения, а остаток распределить по остальным числам. По возможности сохраняя пропорции в процентном соотношении.

Испробовано следующее решение:

```
$limit = 8;

// Вычисление остатка от чисел превышающих $limit.
$rest = array_reduce($percent, function ($a, $b) use ($limit) {
    return $limit < $b ? $a += ($b - $limit) : $a;
});

// Количество чисел не превышающих $limit.
$small = array_reduce($percent, function ($a, $b) use ($limit) {
    return $limit > $b ? ++$a : $a;
});

// Расчёт процентов с ограничением до $limit и добавлением остатка ($rest / $small).
array_walk($percent, function(&$value) use ($limit, $rest, $small) {
    $value = $limit < $value ? min($value, $limit) : $value + ($rest / $small);
});

print_r($percent);
print(array_sum($percent)) . "\n";
```

Данный код работает правильно:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 6.7955555555556
    [5] => 6.1655555555556
    [6] => 5.9755555555556
    [7] => 5.9555555555556
    [8] => 4.3055555555556
    [9] => 4.2455555555556
    [10] => 4.1155555555556
    [11] => 3.9155555555556
    [12] => 3.6755555555556
    [13] => 3.5355555555556
    [14] => 3.0755555555556
    [15] => 2.9455555555556
    [16] => 2.5455555555556
    [17] => 2.3655555555556
    [18] => 2.2355555555556
    [19] => 2.2155555555556
    [20] => 2.0355555555556
    [21] => 1.8955555555556
)
100
```

Но при изменении лимита в переменной $limit до значения "6", появляется превышение лимита за счёт прибавления остатка:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7.24
    [5] => 6.61
    [6] => 6.42
    [7] => 6.4
    [8] => 4.75
    [9] => 4.69
    [10] => 4.56
    [11] => 4.36
    [12] => 4.12
    [13] => 3.98
    [14] => 3.52
    [15] => 3.39
    [16] => 2.99
    [17] => 2.81
    [18] => 2.68
    [19] => 2.66
    [20] => 2.48
    [21] => 2.34
)
100
```

Не могу подобрать подходящий алгоритм вычисления.

Comment: ну так условие задачи тогда меняется, что делать с этим значением percent[5] - заполнить до лимита или не трогать вообще...

Comment: Все значения, превышающие лимит, необходимо ограничить. percent[5] не должен превосходить percent[0] в данном случае.

Comment: ну так прогоняй несколько раз, до тех пор, пока остаток не выровняется по все остальным

Answer (score 0):

Потестить вживую: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/adb68d8dbd5159a4af7e0a503cd81057e92a63da

```php
<?php

const MAX = 100;


$percent = [20.88, 14.93, 14.14, 13.29, 5.06, 4.43, 4.24, 4.22, 2.57, 2.51, 2.38, 2.18, 1.94, 1.80, 1.34, 1.21, 0.81, 0.63, 0.50, 0.48, 0.30, 0.16];
$limit = 2;

// 1 убираем все невалидные значения
$percent = array_filter($percent,fn($item) => $item <= $limit);

// 2 поскольку в конце концов вы хотите уменно, чтобы значения были примерно равны, 
// ставлю сразу среднее в значение(или лимит, если среднее больше)
$avg = MAX / count($percent);
if($avg > $limit)
{
    $avg = $limit;
}

// алей-оп, вуаля
$percent = array_map(fn($item) => $item = $avg,$percent);



print_r(array_values($percent));
print_r(array_sum($percent));
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Всё немного сложнее – требуется сохранить изначальные пропорции процентов, если такое возможно. То есть, сделать их не равно-взвешенными, а такими, в каком виде они были представлены в массиве, но с добавлением остатка.

Comment: тогда, у нас 2 ситуации: 1) мало значений, малый лимит, тогда почти все будут аверажнымы 2) большой лимит, и ваши значения синхронно едут вверх, причём самые большие скорее всего упрутся в лимит. Верно?

Comment: Абсолютно верно.